# Select rows that have not corresponding rows in (foreign key) table

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two tables Say Customers and Orders and the primary key is Customer.CustomerID and Foreign key is Order.CustomerID I want to select all Customers that has not make any orders  in Android Sqlite this is my Query

```
select * from Customer where not exists (select * from Customer  inner join Order on Customer.CustomerID = Order.CustomserID )
```

but it doesn't work and returns 0 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subquery is not a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery), i.e., there is no relation to the outer query.
(The inner `Customer` table is completely independent from the outer one.)
As long as *any* record exists in the database, the EXISTS clause is true for *every* record in the outer `Customer` table.

You want to check whether one particular `Customer` record has matching orders:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Order
                  WHERE CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID)
```

Alternatively, do an [outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join) of the two tables, and check which customers did not get a matching order:

```
SELECT Customer.*
FROM Customer
LEFT JOIN Order USING (CustomerID)
WHERE Order.OrderID IS NULL
```

Alternatively, simply get all customers that are not in the orders table:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer
WHERE CustomerID NOT IN (SELECT CustomerID
                         FROM Order)
```

Comment: another question why you use (USING)
we can rewrite this query like this 
`select * from PlannedVisits left join CheckedVisits on PlannedVisits.PvId = CheckedVisits.PvId where CheckedVisits.PvId  is null`
and it will work very well